# Looking for a non-cryptographic hash function that returns a single character

Tags: algorithms, strings, hashing

Suppose I have a dictionary of ASCII words stored in uppercase.  I also want to save those words into separate files so that the total word count of each file is approximately the same.    By simply looking at the word I need to know which file it should be in (if it's there at all).  Duplicate words should go into the same file and overwrite the last one.

My first attempt at solving this problem is to use .NET's `object.GetHashCode()` function and `.Trim()` to get one of the "random" characters that pop up.  [I asked a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13480913/328397)

If I only use one character of `object.GetHashCode()`  I would get a hash code character of A..Z or 0..9.  However saving the result of GetHashCode to disk is a no-no so I need a substitute.

**Question:**

What [algorithm](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) (or [subset of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/328397)) is appropriate for pigeonholing `strings` into a single character or range of characters (Like hex 0..F offers 16 chars)?

**Real world usage:**

I'll use this answer to modify the Partition key used in Azure Table storage as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13480913/328397)

Comment: Why can't you use a character of `GetHashCode()`?

Comment: So you have a file with arbitrary number of lines of text which you want to save to number of files which have about equal number of lines in them? Now how do hashes have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle The results of `GetHashCode()` may change based on .NET version or patch.  MSFT doesn't want us to save or rely on the hash code in offline storage.  I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @zxcdw I'm looking to use the pigeonhole principle to do Azure LoadBalancing as referenced in the linked question.

Comment: Why not an 8 bit CRC?

Comment: @whatsisname I haven't ever crafted my own CRC.  Do you know of a C# implementation that would work?  I'm reading Wikipedia now.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty implementation: http://www.sanity-free.com/146/crc8_implementation_in_csharp.html

Comment: Can I ask what the general reason is for splitting things up into evenly sized files?  Is that the actual goal, or are you trying to solve a larger problem?

Comment: @GrandmasterB The problem I'm trying to address is high IO to a specific Azure Table (or Blob) Partition (container).  A repeatable one or two character checksum applied as a suffix to each blob or container will allow me to load balance my partitions naturally, increase scale, and efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest 'hash' function would be to take the first character of the string and that is the hash code.  It works.  It doesn't have a good distribution, but it works for some degree of 'works'.

To get a better hash, sum up the value of the string (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 ...) and then take the modulus of the resulting value.  If this is to be assigned to the 'A-Z' hash range, take this mod 26 and assign that back into the character array (in this case, A = 0).  If this is to be in the hex range hash, take the value mod 16.

Comment: Yeah, the first character is probably a bad idea, you'd get too many T's.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle The pendant in me says its actually S, C, P, B, M for the first character.  S has 16k starting letters while 'T' has only 7.5k starting. `cut -c1 words | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` -- and yes, they are very poorly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like your question is very related to your previous [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480913/using-a-subset-of-gethashcode-to-increase-azuretable-performance-through-parti) question.

> Generally speaking, Azure Table IO performance improves as more partitions are used (with some tradeoffs in continuation tokens and batch updates I won't go into).
>
> Since the partition key is always a string I am considering using a "natural" load balancing technique based on a subset of the GetHashCode() of the partition key, and appending this subset to the partition key itself. This will allow all direct PK/RK queries to be computed with little overhead and with ease. Batch updates may just need an intermediate to group similar PKs together prior to submission

With that background information the problem is not simply taking a database of words and splitting into multiple smaller but equal sized databases of the same words. Instead it looks like you are trying to determine how to automatically partition your data based on a key so that it is separated into equal parts.

If our end goal is to partition the words evenly across the shards I would not do so based on the data itself. That is to say if my method for determining which partition a bit of data goes into is based on what is included in that data I would not expect my end distribution to be even.

Given the follow list of words as an example

> Programmer,Programmer,StackExchange

The value **Programmer** is repeated twice. If that value is what I am using to determine which partition the data will end up in I would expect that both Programmers would end up in the same partition. If the end goal is to keep all closely related words on the same partition this may be the way you want to go, but I don't think it is.

If instead we do not care which words are where and want an even distribution I would first determine the number of shards that I want to run and then simply loop through my database of words assigning the partition key 1-N where N is the number of partitions I have.

i.e.

```
int totalPartitions = 5;
int currentPartition = 1;
Foreach(var item in MyData) {
  MyData.PartitionKey = currentPartition;
  if(currentPartition < totalPartitions)
    currentPartition++
  else
    currentPartition = 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is related to the SO question.  When that question was migrated I learned that I need to ask *algorithm* questions on Programmers.SE.  Back to this question... if the ASCII version of `PROGRAMMERS == PROGRAMMERS` (and they are equal and not similar) then I want my app to be able to calculate what Azure partition the word is in.  Knowing this allows me to gain efficiency with batch features and be able to directly query one partition rather than guessing at which partition the data is in.

Comment: If you want to be able to determine the partition for any string with no other data than the ASCII string itself then I believe you will have to settle for an uneven distribution of your data. If we use just the string PROGRAMMER to get another key that represents a partition, we have no way to distinguish it from another string with the same exact contents. Knowing that, we can see that a database of 100 identical strings would end up in one partition.

Comment: Yes, I don't care about historic data if it's overwritten with a match.  Yes distribution will not be perfectly even, but I need a way to make it reasonably even for performance. Perhaps an 8 bit CRC of "PROGRAMMERS" gives me "8".  I would then save the value into the partition "PROGRAMMERS8".  I just need an algorithm that load balances strings.  Maybe 8 bit CRC, or MichaelT's answer is correct.